# order-column does not seem to work

Tags: jpa-2.0, hyperjaxb

I have defined my bindings in the following way

```
 <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='Parent']">
   ...........
  <jaxb:bindings node="xs:element[@name='children']">
        <hj:one-to-many name="children" fetch="EAGER">
           <orm:order-column name="CHILD_PRIMARY_KEY"/>
            <orm:join-column name="PARENT_PRIMARY_KEY"/>
        </hj:one-to-many>
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>

But the generated class has OrderColumn annotation missing.

i.e
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Children.class, cascade = {
        CascadeType.ALL
    }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_PRIMARY_KEY")
    public List<Children> getChildren() {
        if (Childrens== null) {
            childrens= new ArrayList<Children>();
        }
        return this.childrens;
    }
```

I am expecting OrderColumn annotation with OneToMany and JoinColumn. But it does not seem to be there, please can some one help whether i am missing something here?

Comment: OK, i have set the variant to jap2 which seems to make the order column annotation work. But i also overriden default naming strategy. Now naming strategy plug in does not get called, just because  i added <variant>jap2</variant> in my pom. any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your `org\jvnet\hyperjaxb3\ejb\plugin\custom\applicationContext.xml` to `org\jvnet\hyperjaxb3\ejb\jpa2\plugin\custom\applicationContext.xml`.